# Average length of sequence with consecutive values >100 (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to identify the length of consecutive sequences within an array that are >100. I have found the longest sequence using the following code but need to alter to also find the average length.

```
def getLongestSeq(a, n): 
    maxIdx = 0
    maxLen = 0
    currLen = 0
    currIdx = 0
    for k in range(n): 
        if a[k] >100: 
            currLen +=1
             # New sequence, store 
            # beginning index. 
            if currLen == 1: 
                currIdx = k 
        else: 
            if currLen > maxLen: 
                maxLen = currLen 
                maxIdx = currIdx 
            currLen = 0

    if maxLen > 0: 
        print('Index : ',maxIdx,',Length : ',maxLen,) 
    else: 
        print("No positive sequence detected.") 

# Driver code 
arrQ160=resultsQ1['60s']
n=len(arrQ160)
getLongestSeq(arrQ160, n)

arrQ260=resultsQ2['60s']
n=len(arrQ260)
getLongestSeq(arrQ260, n)

arrQ360=resultsQ3['60s']
n=len(arrQ360)
getLongestSeq(arrQ360, n)

arrQ460=resultsQ4['60s']
n=len(arrQ460)
getLongestSeq(arrQ460, n)
```

*output*

```
Index :  12837 ,Length :  1879
Index :  6179 ,Length :  3474
Index :  1164 ,Length :  1236
Index :  2862 ,Length :  617
```

Comment: Avoid indexing if possible.  Use python excellent iteration features instead

Comment: What do you mean by average length ? length of what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def get_100_lengths( arr ) :
    s = ''.join( ['0' if i < 100 else '1' for i in arr] )
    parts = s.split('0')
    return [len(p) for p in parts if len(p) > 0]
```

After that you may calculate an average or do whatever you like.

The result:

```
>>> get_100_lengths( [120,120,120,90,90,120,90,120,120] )
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: wow, I did not thought about this approach, this is quite interesting

Comment: And lenik if I now wanted to know the index where each beigns so I can calculate time between? so for your example above I would get [0:3, 5:1, 7:2]

Comment: @Jake you may want to ask another question, because this seems like a bit different problem that requires a bit different solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632056/location-index-of-consecutive-values-within-a-dataframe-python

Answer (score 1):

that might be a little tricky. You want to use one variable to keep track of sum of length, one variable to keep track of how many times a sequence occurred. 
We can determine if a sequence terminated when current number<100 and previous number is greater than 100

```
def getLongestSeq(array): 
    total_length = total_ct = 0
    last_is_greater = False 
    for number in array:
        if number > 100: 
            total_length += 1 
            last_is_greater = True
        elif number<100 and last_is_greater:
            total_ct += 1 
            last_is_greater = False 
    return round(total_length / total_ct)
```

Did not test this code, please comment if there is any issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time spent! I ended up using the method provided by lenik which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all the sequences, take their lengths, and get the average.  Each of those steps are relatively straightforward.

```
items = [1, 101, 1, 101, 101, 1, 101, 101, 101, 1]
```

Finding sequences: use `groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = groupby(items, lambda x: x > 100)  # (False, [1]), (True, [101]), ...
```

Find lengths (careful, iterable of iterables not a list):

```
lens = [len(g) for k, g in groups if k]  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Find average (assumes at least one):

```
avg = float(sum(lens)) / len(lens)  # 2.0
```