# Location (index) of consecutive values within a dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify the location of different ocurrences of consequtive values within a dataframe.

I am using the following code to identify and count the number of ocurrences within each consecutive sequence

```
def get_150_lengths( array ) :
    s = ''.join( ['0' if i <150 else '1' for i in resultsQ4['60s']] )
    parts = s.split('0')
    return [len(p) for p in parts if len(p) > 0]

Q4150 = get_150_lengths(resultsQ4['60s'])
Q4150 = pd.DataFrame(Q4150)
```

As an example this provides me with 2 values
600
58

This relates to two sequences within my dataframe where values are >150 and returns the count in each sequence.

What I would like to return is where those consecutive sequences begin with an index

Comment: `array` argument is not actually used inside the function =)

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, so how do I adjust to use the array argument within the function? Do I need to set resultsQ4['60s'] as the array?

Comment: inside the function, replace `resultsQ4['60s']` with `array` -- that should do the trick